# 0 == selected is true when selected is 2 in android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I'm working on an app for a school project and need to store a value in room db.

```
@Entity
data class Selected(
    var selected: String,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val id: Int = 0
)

@Dao
interface SelectedDao {
    @Upsert
    suspend fun upsertSelected(selected: Selected)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Selected")
    fun getSelected(): Flow<Selected>
}

@Database(
    entities = [Selected::class],
    version = 1
)
abstract class SelectedDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val dao: SelectedDao
}

sealed interface SelectedEvent {
    object SaveSelected: SelectedEvent
}

data class SelectedState (
    val selected: Selected = Selected("0")
)

class SelectedViewModel(
    private val dao: SelectedDao
): ViewModel() {
    private val _selected = dao.getSelected()
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), Selected("2"))

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(SelectedState())
    val state = combine(_state, _selected) { state, selected ->
        state.copy(
            selected = selected
        )
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), SelectedState())

    fun onEvent(event: SelectedEvent) {
        when(event) {
            SelectedEvent.SaveSelected -> {
                val s = state.value.selected.selected
                if (s.isBlank()) return
                val selected = Selected(s)

                viewModelScope.launch {
                    dao.upsertSelected(selected)
                }

                _state.update { it.copy(
                    selected = Selected(s)
                ) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my activity

```
class SettingActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val db by lazy {
        Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            SelectedDatabase::class.java,
            "selected.db"
        ).build()
    }

    private val viewModel by viewModels<SelectedViewModel>(
        factoryProducer = {
            object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
                override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                    return SelectedViewModel(db.dao) as T
                }
            }
        }
    )
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()
            RasporedTheme {
                Homescreen(state, viewModel::onEvent)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Homescreen(
    state: SelectedState,
    onEvent: (SelectedEvent) -> Unit
) {
    val selected: Int = state.selected.selected.toInt()
    Log.d("CHECK SELECTED VALUE", "${state.selected.selected} $selected")

    val radioButtons = remember {
        mutableStateListOf(
            ToggleableInfo(
                isChecked = selected == 0,
                text = "Prva"
            ),
            ToggleableInfo(
                isChecked = selected == 1,
                text = "Druga"
            ),
            ToggleableInfo(
                isChecked = selected == 2,
                text = "Treca"
            )
        )
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color(0xff000000)),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Settings",
            fontSize = 32.sp,
            color = Color.White,
        )
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(10.dp, 0.dp, 10.dp, 0.dp)
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp))
                .background(Color(0xff171717))
                .padding(10.dp),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Grupa:",
                color = Color(0xfffafafa),
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 5.dp)
            )
            radioButtons.forEachIndexed { index, info ->
                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(end = 16.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .clickable {
                            dataProcessor.grupa = index
                            state.selected.selected = index.toString()
                            onEvent(SelectedEvent.SaveSelected)
                            radioButtons.replaceAll {
                                it.copy(
                                    isChecked = it.text == info.text
                                )
                            }
                        }
                ) {
                    RadioButton(
                        selected = info.isChecked,
                        onClick = {
                            dataProcessor.grupa = index
                            state.selected.selected = index.toString()
                            radioButtons.replaceAll {
                                it.copy(
                                    isChecked = it.text == info.text
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = info.text,
                        color = Color(0xfffafafa),
                        fontSize = 18.sp
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using app inspector and the correct value is stored but when I load the activity it defaults to selecting the first radio button even though the condition selected == 0 should be false. When I log the value it

Answer (score 0):

The initial value of `selected` in `SelectedState` is "0".
However, in your `SelectedViewModel`, the initial state of `_selected` is `Selected("2")`. That might cause unexpected behavior.
Try and make sure the initial values are consistent across your [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) and `State`.

Also,  you are converting the `selected` `String` to an `Int` for comparison. That can be error-prone and might not always work as expected if the string is not a valid integer.
Convert `selected` to an Int safely and handle potential exceptions.

The logic within the `RadioButton` click listener seems to be updating the state directly. It is better to handle all state updates through your `ViewModel` to maintain unidirectional data flow: move all state-modifying logic to the `ViewModel`.

```bash
┌─────────────────────┐     ┌──────────────────────┐     ┌──────────────────────────┐
│   SettingActivity   │     │   SelectedViewModel  │     │   SelectedDatabase &     │
│   - Creates View    │────│   - Handles State &  │────│     SelectedDao          │
└─────────────────────┘     │     Logic Management │     │   - Database Operations  │
                            └──────────────────────┘     └──────────────────────────┘
                                    ▲                                      ▲
                                    │                                      │
                                    │                                      │
                                    │                                      │
                                    │                                      │
                         ┌────────────────────────┐                        │
                         │  Homescreen Composable │───────────────────────┘
                         │  - UI Rendering &      │
                         │    Event Handling      │
                         └────────────────────────┘
```

Your code would then be:

```kotlin
class SelectedViewModel(
    // your code
) {
    // your code

    fun setSelectedValue(value: String) {
        // Safe conversion and update logic
        val intValue = value.toIntOrNull() ?: return
        _state.update { it.copy(selected = Selected(value)) }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Homescreen(
    // your code
) {
    val selected = state.selected.selected.toIntOrNull() ?: 0
    // your code

    radioButtons.forEachIndexed { index, info ->
        // your code
        .clickable {
            viewModel.setSelectedValue(index.toString())
            // your code
        }
    }
}
```